# Overriding mutable variable in child class in Scala

Tags: scala

i have a abstract class and a child class that extends it

```
abstract class User{
var name : String =  "test"
}
```

I have another class

```
class Student(name : String) extends User{

}
```

now whenever i try to pass the name making an object of student and then prints the value on console instead of showing me the name i passed in the constructor it shows the **test** from the parent class

```
object main extends App{
  val st = new student("ahsen")
  var name = st.name

  println("name is " + name) 
}
```

it outputs

> name is test

please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't override a var. Maybe assign it?

```
class Student(n: String) extends User {
  name = n
}
```

Alternatively you can define `name` as a `var` in `Student`, but only if the superclass only declares the variable, not defining it:

```
abstract class User {
  var name: String
}
class Student(var name: String) extends User
```